# How to use Puppeteer in an Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, puppeteer, e2e-testing

My question is simple but I don't understand if it's possible and, in this case, how it's possible.

I would like to use the [`puppeteer`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) library in an Angular application using the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer), but I don't understand how I can use it.

For example I just want to make this script :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

In an Angular component, can somebody help me (it will be able me to understanding a lot of thing).

Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad English, I'm French.

Answer (score 27):

## How to use Angular e2e testing with Puppeteer

### 1) Install [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

```
npm install --save-dev puppeteer @types/puppeteer
```

### 2) Configure Protractor to use Puppeteer

Edit your `protractor.conf.js` and add the following inside `capabilities`:

```
// ...
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

exports.config = {
  // ...
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless'],
      binary: puppeteer.executablePath(),
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

### 3) Write and execute your tests

For example, edit your `e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts` and do the following:

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  it('Test Puppeteer screenshot', async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:4200');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

    await browser.close();
  });
});
```

Run your e2e tests using `ng e2e`. The above example will produce a screenshot of your app home page and save it as `example.png`.

---

Check the [official Puppeteer website](https://pptr.dev/) for more information about how to write tests.

Comment: Does it work with chromedriver? I met this error:  `E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74`

Comment: Doesnt work, I am getting an error, 

E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75

Comment: There's puppeteer-core which is what they recommend to use w/out downloading chromium. There might be differences between browser versions depending on puppeteer-core version. However, the puppeteer full version is guaranteed to work since it downloads the chromium as per the documentation
https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=master&show=api-puppeteer-vs-puppeteer-core

Comment: @artificerpi you have to make sure your version of chrome/chromium is compatible with the chromedriver/webdriver version that you are using.

Comment: @Francesco How do you start the Angular/Puppeteer application if I `don't` want to run any tests, just run a headless browser? is it also `ng e2e` ?

Comment: @ps0604 sorry it's been a while I don't use Puppeteer, I can't help you

Comment: One note, don't forget to run `webdriver-update` after configuring Puppeteer, I had a Chrome version mismatch error until I did this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Puppeteer as a modern smart alternative to Angular Universal for server side rendering and pre-rendering. When using Puppeteer for this purpose, unlike Angular Universal, you don't need to modify your project source code. Using Puppeteer seems significantly easier than Universal.

References:

[Headless Chrome: an answer to server-side rendering JS sites](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/articles/ssr)

[Prerender an Angular application with @angular/cli and puppeteer](https://blog.cloudboost.io/prerender-an-angular-application-with-angular-cli-and-puppeteer-25dede2f0252)

Answer (score 3):

Latest versions of Angular CLI and Puppeteer have an integration. Now you can add Puppeteer by running `ng e2e` and choosing Puppeteer from the dropdown. Alternatively, you can install `@puppeteer/ng-schematics` directly by running `ng add @puppeteer/ng-schematics`. See https://pptr.dev/integrations/ng-schematics for more details.