# Angular E2E with Puppeteer but WITHOUT webdriver

Tags: angular, webdriver, puppeteer

I'm running our Angular E2E tests with Puppeteer. This works fine but Protractor is still including webdriver even though it isn't actually needed since Puppeteer handles the connection to and manipulation of Chrome.

How can I run Angular E2E tests using Puppeteer without requiring webdriver?

I followed the instructions here:

[How to use Puppeteer in an Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536244/how-to-use-puppeteer-in-an-angular-application)

Which continues to use protractor which then requires webdriver.

I also reviewed this example that uses Angular and Puppeteer but it also uses protractor and runs webdriver unnecessarily.

https://github.com/Quramy/angular-puppeteer-demo

Comment: What I found out so far: You can avoid starting selenium by using the "Mock" webdriver (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/index.ts) and you can disable the update of the chrome-driver (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753228/how-to-stop-protractor-from-downloading-latest-chromedriver)